# missing 'ldconfig' and 'start-stop-daemon'

Tags: python

when I tried to install numpy and pandas, I got this problem. Can you help me? Thank you!

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu12.04. 

thank you for your post!

Comment: Have you tried installing the Ubuntu packages? `$sudo apt-get install python-pandas` (this will install `numpy` automatically as a dependency).